# Implementing Word2Vec for stemming/lemmatizing Turkish

Tags: python, nlp, word2vec

I'm working on building a stemming programm for Turkish which is a morphologically rich language. None of the ressources that I've found are accurate enough for my purpose and I don't think they are built on deep learning technology.

How could I use word embeddings to train a stemmer/lemmatizer? What are the main steps I should be considering?

Comment: did you any updates?

Comment: You may want to check out these resources. https://tscorpus.com , https://github.com/akoksal/Turkish-Word2Vec/blob/master/README.md